# How to display text or anything without form frames?

Tags: c#

For example, on the second monitor I want to display the text I wrote in the textbox, but without form frames, just black background and white letters.

Comment: You really need to provide some context as to what you are trying to accomplish in order to get answers. Posting code you have already tried would be preferable.

Comment: You can create a form without borders,  Set FormBorderStyle to None and the BackColor to Black, and then place a label on that form and set its ForeColor to White.

Comment: Thank you Casperah, that helped me much. Sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `Form` transparent (I assume that you are working with WinForms).

- Set the `BackColor` of the form to some color that will be used as transparent color (e.g. Color.Red).
- Set the `TransparencyKey` to the same color.
- Set `FormBoderStyle` to `None`

Or you can give any color to the background without making it transparent. Just don't define the `TransparencyKey`. The important part is setting the `FormBoderStyle` to `None`. This not only hides the border but the title bar together with the form icon and the control box.

Then place a `Label` on that form with the desired text. That's it.

Comment: Do you also need to set ControlBox to false? Also you may want to set ShowInTaskbar to false. But be careful, you need a way, either in the parent form, or the form itself, to end execution, otherwise you're stuck using TaskManager to end it.

Comment: Also ShowIcon may need to be set to False

Comment: @Wanabrutbeer: If you set `FormBoderStyle` to `None` the title bar will not be shown at all. This dismisses the icon and the control box automatically. (tested)